# Firefox not trusting LetsEncrypt SSL from IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, iis-8, letsencrypt

My Lets Encrypt certificates are working on all browsers except Firefox.

I have seen this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611180/lets-encrypt-certificate-not-trusted-on-firefox) but I do not know how to do the following

> I would recommend configuring IIS to serve the full certificate chain instead of just the domain certificate, as well as disable support for SSLv3, if possible. If Firefox still doesn't like your certificate after that, more in-depth troubleshooting may be necessary.

I have disabled SSLv3 so far.

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using as the web server?

Comment: I am using IIS 8.0

Comment: Use this https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html to see if your sever is providing the full certificate chain.

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/257-resolving-issues-with-android-and-comodo-ssl-on-iis-server/

Comment: What worked exactly? :)  If you want to pay back, please post an answer to your own question (it's allowed, and appreciated) detailing exactly what you did (citing any applicable web pages as sources).

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the [link](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) and checked there what issues the SSL has, it appeared that SSLV3 caused firefox to reject the SSL, so I did further digging and noticed that by disabling it only in IIS did not resolve the issue. then I have imported the intermediate certificate from Lets Encrypt into windows intermediate store, I have also disabled automatic certificate updates on Windows and Restarted IIS now I can browse my website in Firefox, Chrome, Edge, IE etc